# поиск числа в массиве

Tags: python

есть ли в питоне быстрый способ найти числа в массиве,  и вывести их.

`filter_arr([1,2,'a','b'])` чтобы вернуло  [1,2]

любы числа 1,2,3,5,.... кроме отрицательных

Comment: для начала неплохо было бы определится что вы считаете числом... Какие из следующих значений вы считаете числами: `[1.23, '1.2', 'nan', 'inf', '012', '0x12']` ?

Comment: ох ты , елки моталки, любы числа 1,2,3,5,.... кроме отрицательных

Comment: А нуль? так до бесконечности же можно=) Хотим тип данных

Comment: "Быстрый" - это в смысле у вас много чисел и вы хотите, чтобы работало не слишком долго, или под "быстрый" вы имели в виду "простой"? )

Comment: а вот с типами отчлиынй вопрос, это же фундамент, где есть информация по типам данных в питоне* ?

Comment: @CrazyElf быстрый чтобы при больших объемах  расходывать ресурсы по минимуму

Answer (score 2):

если массив неотсортированный, то все равно равно придется просмотреть все элементы, так что от O(n) никуда не деться,

если записи отсортированы, то легко провести бинарный поиск и найти границы отрицательных и положительных чисел, положительных чисел и не чисел (например, строк) и сложность будет O(log(n)), после чего выделить нужные вам числа, впрочем если условия сортировки задать так, чтобы натуральные числа были старше всего остального, а отрицательные целы больше, чем все кроме натуральных, тогда надо будет найти только 1 границу, а не 2

ну и остаётся вопрос, считать ли строки с числами - числами
`'123'`, `1e2`, `0x12` и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь только о целых положительных (из комментария):

```
res = [el for el in arr if type(el) == int and el > 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример:

```
import numbers
arr = [1,2,'a','b']
print( list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x , numbers.Number) , arr)) )
```